# how prevent shopping cart 'count' in navbar from getting crunched at different widths

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, bootstrap-4

My shopping cart span showing the number of items in the cart keeps getting crunched when I shrink the display size. I have changed all elements to `inline` but it still isn't working. I have also fiddled with the margins and it still is crunching it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attached my css, html and a screenshot.

CSS

```
.icons-right {
    margin-right: -5%;
    width: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.icons-right i {
    display: inline;
}
.icons-right a {
    display: inline;
}

.icons-right li {
        padding-left: 1.1em;
        padding-right: 1.1em;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 0px;
        display: inline;
    }

#cartSpan {
    display: inline;
}
```

```
<!-- ICONS RIGHT -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse icons-right navbar-expand" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if(login){ %>
        <li class="nav-item" id="loginRegister">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/user/profile"><i class="fas fa-user fa-md"></i></a>
        </li>
      <% } else { %>
        <li class="nav-item" id="loginRegister">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/user/signin"><i class="fas fa-user fa-md"></i></a>
        </li>
      <% } %>
      <li class="nav-item" id="findRetailer">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/dealers"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-md"></i> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="shoppingCart">

        <a class="nav-link" href="/shopping-cart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-md"></i> <% if(session.cart){ %> <%if(session.cart.totalQty > 0 || null) { %> <span  id="cartSpan" class="badge">(<%=  session.cart.totalQty  %>) </span>   <% } %> <% } %>  </a>

      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[Screenshot at 1325 px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWTFI.png)

Comment: inline doesnt always work; increse the width of the li tag and make the a and i as inline-block

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. I appreciate the help.